# select all but the last record from grouped record in a table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select all but the last row of grouped data from a table.

```
+----+--------+--------+                    +----+--------+--------+
| id | userID | amount |                    | id | userID | amount |
+----+--------+--------+                    +----+--------+--------+
| 1  | 20     | 400    |                    | 1  | 20     | 400    |
| 2  | 20     | 200    |                    | 2  | 20     | 200    |
| 3  | 21     | 100    |         =>         | 3  | 21     | 100    |
| 4  | 11     | 500    |                    | 4  | 11     | 500    |
| 5  | 11     | 250    |                    | 6  | 21     | 50     |
| 6  | 21     | 50     |                    
| 7  | 20     | 100    |                    
| 8  | 21     | 200    |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I have tried to use the query

```
SELECT *
  FROM table 
 WHERE userID != (SELECT MAX(userID) FROM table) 
 GROUP 
    BY userID
```

but it only fetches one unique row of data even though there are more left

Comment: How many different userIDs are there in the table?

Comment: If you do a SELECT * and a GROUP BY userID, you will get an error that not all columns are in group by or aggregated.

Comment: Why do you group at all? There's no aggregation function in your outer query. And your use of aggregation is wrong anyway unless the table only has one column.

Comment: I have up to 10 userIDs and some occour more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g....

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MAX(id) id 
         FROM my_table
        GROUP 
           BY userid 
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id 
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not aggreagtion function so you don't need  group by

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE userID != ( 
  SELECT MAX(userID) FROM table
)
```

This can happen with mysql version <5.7  for mysql version > 5.7 (by default setting)  this use of group by raise an error

Comment: So how am i supposed to make sure the result is grouped by userIDs which are more than one?

Comment: looking to your sample seems that you are looking for all the rows  for each user_id but not the rows  with the lowest amount  (and not the rows different form the last user_id) ..